# <ImplicitUsings> in .NET8 project, any vulnerabilities?

Tags: c#, .net, csproj, implicit-usings

Using the upgrade-assistant provided by MS, i'm trying to upgrade my projects from .NET 6 to 8.

I have noticed this being inserted at the top of my project files : `<ImplicitUsings>enabled</ImplicitUsings>`

[image: Inserted ImplicitUsings in csproj]

Does `<ImplicitUsings>` provide any possible attack vector for my projects? I have a feeling that libraries can be hijacked this way.

Anyone have any information?
Thanks!

Comment: If you're worried about implicit usings, why not disable them?

Comment: should i be worried is the question

Comment: Why are you worried about vulnerabilities? The only thing `ImplicitUsings` does is add some `global using` statements based on your project type so you don't have to repeat the same `using` statements in every file. You can find the list of namespaces added [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview#implicit-using-directives)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it won't cause any issues. Implicit usings allow you to remove a number of commonly used `using` statements from each file by referring to one location and you can customise it if you wish to through the csproj settings. It will generate a `ProjectName.GlobalUsings.g.cs` file with the following by default.

[image: Global usings]

Answer (score 5):

There is no risk to your project. It is just cleaning up the `using` declarations at the top of your file. It isn't adding any references to your project.

Answer (score 2):

For system libraries (out-of-the-box .Net dlls), things are are signed. This means no one can just drop a new evil .dll with matching names over top of a system library and expect your program to invoke bad things.

For third party libraries, you still need a reference in the project file. So you can omit the `using` directive in the code in individual files, but any additional "hidden" libraries that might be invoked from code still need to be referenced in the project for the program to build properly. Therefore you still have a way to audit and restrict what libraries are included.

For both options, you still need a global entry for which directives can be skipped with the project file, so you can look there as well.

Answer (score 1):

It just applies global using specified by the Project's SDK.
It's not vulnerable at all.